# Javascript checkbox validation - disable and enable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of 3 checkboxes and I need to apply some conditions/restrictions for them.

[image: Checkboxes]

For example, if I tick the first checkbox `{{UTEP}}` i'll have to disable the last one `Valências`.

I have the following code:

```
var _restricoes = [[1, 2]];
```

$($('#conteudoCategorias').find('.clsF3MInput')).on('click', function (e) {
    debugger
    //get elems
    var _id = parseInt($(this).attr("id").replace("CheckBox", ""));

```
for (var i = 0; i < _restricoes.length; i++) {
    //get item
    var _item = _restricoes[i];
    //verifica se existe
    var _existe = $.grep(_item, (x) => x === _id)[0];
    if (_existe && CategoriasAnexosVerificaCheck($(this)) === true) {
        //get other value
        var _otherValue = $.grep(_item, (x) => x !== _id)[0];

        //bloquear elementos
        var elemsBloquear = $.grep($('#conteudoCategorias :input'), function (elem) {
            return elem.getAttribute('id') !== 'CheckBox' + _id &&
                elem.getAttribute('id') !== 'CheckBox' + _otherValue;
        });

        $(elemsBloquear).attr('disabled', true);

        //desbloquear elementos
        var elemsDesbBloquear = $.grep($('#conteudoCategorias :input'), function (elem) {
            elem.getAttribute('id') === 'CheckBox' + _id;
            elem.getAttribute('id') === 'CheckBox' + _otherValue;
        });

        $(elemsDesbBloquear).attr('disabled', false);
    }
}
```

});

When I uncheck the `{{UTEP}}` I need to enable the checkbox `Valências` again, but I can't get to it.
the array _restricoes contains the ids of the checkboxes that can be checked. If I check the first one, I can check the second one, and vice-versa. The array will have more conditions/restrictions, like this for example: _restricoes = [[1, 2], [1, 4]];

Note: The Ids of the checkboxes are dynamic, they are generated from the server, puting it simpler: the number of registrations are the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a weird combination between jQuery and javascript. Here is a jQuery solution how you can change the enabled property based on the checked property of another checkbox.

```js
$('#utepId').on('change', function(){
  //when #utepId is checked disable #ValenciasId
  $('#ValenciasId').prop('disabled', $(this).prop('checked'));
  //when #utepId is checked uncheck #ValenciasId
  if($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('#ValenciasId').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="utepId" type=checkbox /><label for="utepId">utep</label>
<input id="candbId" type=checkbox /><label for="candbId">candb</label>
<input id="ValenciasId" type=checkbox /><label for="ValenciasId">Valências</label>
```

Comment: Yeah, I've used it mixed up because I wasn't able to figure it out :/
does your solution contemplates an array of arrays (ex: [[1,2], [3,4], ...])?

Thank you for your help!